# InfoPath close form by code

Tags: development, infopath

I'm creating an InfoPath form in InfoPath 2010 Designer, that will be running in InfoPath 2007 and 2010 clients and contains C# code.

When the user clicks the submit button I need to execute some C# code, then submit and close. I can add the submit to the C# code, but closing the form seems only possible from a rule (which whould execute before the code).

I found and tried a hint, to configure the form to close automatically after the submit, but somehow this isn't working. Are there other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply add the following to your C# code...no need for a rule or the "close automatically after submit" form setting.

```
XDocument.View.Window.Close(true);
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT:  My apologies...I gave you a method for scripting the close, that object is not accessible via C#.  I was able to setup a form where the submit executed some C# code and set the "After Submit" option to "Close the form" and it worked fine for me.

[image]

Is this what you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Intellisense can't find XDocument, which Assembly do I have to reference? This isn't the Lync class XDocument, is it? Because I can't find a View property in that one...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.infopath.xdocument.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it, your code sample looks, like View is a static property of XDocument. But the msdn link says, XDocument is an interface, so it can't have static properties. How can I get an instance of XDocument for my current form?

Comment: Hey thanks, now it is working. Yes this was what I tried, but I didn't use "Perform custom action using Code". I used the "Send form data to a single destination" and had the form code behind a button. At the end of the code I called this.Submit(), expecting it to trigger the settings from this dialog. But it didn't. Now with the code in the submit options, it is working :D