# C# save/submit to sharepoint from infopath

Tags: 2007, development, infopath

I have tried this.Submit(), this.Save(), but neither seem to actually work. Is there a simple way of doing this? I have also tried using a submit button and then using custom rules for that, but still nothing. Finally, I tried doing Execute, but still nothing. Save gives a securty exception (think it needs full trust), and submit just never submits then gives a dialog saying so. Any simple ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the same problem, but please look at this post:

[InfoPath close form by code](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16861/infopath-close-form-by-code/16862#16862)

The issue they were having had to do with how they were invoking the code-behind...i.e. they were using "Send form data to a single destination" and had the form code behind a button versus using "Perform custom action using Code" from the Submit Options dialog.

Comment: That is what I have at the moment, and submit just fails, saying 'InfoPath cannot submit the form.  The OnSubmitRequest even handler returned a value indicating that the submit failed.' Any idea? Is there something that is different if you are submitting to a sharepoint site?

Comment: Did you see if there is anything in the ULS? Maybe turn on verbose logging for the Forms Services category in CA and see if that reveals anything.