# How do I close an InfoPath form page programmatically?

Tags: infopath, forms-services

Is it possible to close an InfoPath form displayed in Forms Services via C#? I know I can close the form, but the actual InfoPath frame is still there.

Is there anyway to kill the process from within the form code itself, or is this impossible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# save/submit to sharepoint from infopath](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17341/c-save-submit-to-sharepoint-from-infopath)

Comment: sorry, they were two seperate issues I am having. Did not mean to duplicate.

Comment: Have you tried using Application.Quit()?

Answer (score 1):

```
FormEvents_Submit(null, null);
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://yoursite.com", false);
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. System.Web.HttpContext isn't in by binaries. Also, wouldn't this just open another web page?